# determining if sequence has upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, harmonic-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am somewhat stuck in my calculations when determining if sequence has an upper bound.

The sequence $$x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+..+\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}$$ 
Is equal to $$\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}}+..+\frac{1}{1+\frac{n}{n}})$$

And so I notice that all the denominators are greater than 1, which means that all terms in the parentheses are less than 1.

But how can I determine further if there is an upper bound?

Comment: ... and there are $n$ of them.

Comment: @Zeekless  so the sequence should be less than (1/n) * n = 1 is that correct?

Comment: You can find some posts deriving various upper bounds on this site. E.g.,
[Proof for $\log\frac{2n+1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}<\log 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/957977),
[Inequality $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k} \le \frac{3}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2384268), 
[For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that: $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{5}{6}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2831505) or [An interesting inequality $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}<\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \ n\ge1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809019).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The largest term is the first, so an obvious upper bound is to set all terms equal to the first one and get
$$
x_n < \frac{n}{n+1} <1.
$$

You could also say that, since the last term is the smallest, one has
$$
x_n > \frac{n}{2n} = \frac 12,
$$

which means that $\frac 12 < x_n < 1, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 10):

By C-S $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+i}=1+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n+i}-\frac{1}{n}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{n+i}=$$
$$=1-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i^2}{ni+i^2}\leq1-\frac{1}{n}\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(ni+i^2)}=1-\frac{1}{n}\frac{\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}}{\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}=$$
$$=1-\frac{3(n+1)}{2(5n+1)}=\frac{7n-1}{10n+2}<\frac{7}{10}.$$
Actually, $$\ln2=0.6931...$$
Cauchy-Schwarz forever!

Actually, by calculus we can show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+i}=\ln2.$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice the Riemann sum
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{1+k/n} < \int_0^1\frac{dt}{1+t} = \log 2$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

For each $n\ne 0$,

$$\frac{1}{n+1}\le \frac{1}{n}$$
$$\frac{1}{n+2}\le \frac{1}{n}$$
...

$$\frac{1}{2n}\le \frac 1n$$

You can finish.